# Triangle similarity in Euclidean/ Hyperbolic geometries

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

A pair of parallel lines (red) is cut by  two transversals (blue) through point P in Euclidean and  Poincare half plane models.

Would alternate angles be equal in either case in similar triangles between parallels?

[image]

Although drawn to scale it does not seem so in the latter case. Is the construction correct/valid?

Thanks for comment.

Comment: in the hyperbolic plane, similar triangles are congruent.  Triangles that are not congruent are not similar

Comment: The Alternate Interior Angle Theorem asserts that, if alternate interior angles are equal then the lines are parallel.  The converse does not hold in hyperbolic geometry, i.e., there are parallel lines and a transversal whose alternate interior angles are not equal.

Comment: You can pick a transversal so that one of the interior angles is (arbitrarily close to) $0$ while the other is not.

Comment: @ Will Jagy:  In other words..  barring congruence, hyperbolic triangles are *never* similar .. right?

Comment: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf

Comment: Thank you. You mentioned (page 5, Squaring the circle ) that similar hyperbolic triangles  should necessarily be congruent. In the Wiki on Hyperbolic cosine law it says that  there is no Euclidean analogue of the second/extra cosine law since hyperbolic triangle lengths involve interior angles. Is the remark also relevant here?